# Android returning different instance of ViewModel for the same fragment when calling ft.replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I have a container Fragment, call it `ContainerFragment` holding two fragments, `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`. Both, `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` create a `ViewModel` in the `onCreate()` method using the `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` approach.

Let's assume that container can only show one fragment at a time and I'm using the `FragmentTransaction.replace()` method to switch between `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`. In my case, I show `FragmentA`, which creates the `FragmentA` ViewModel and then an action triggers `FragmentB` to replace `FragmentA`. Now, when I'm done with `FragmentB`, I call replace again to show `FragmentA`. Here is the check I do in that method that replaces the fragments:

```
if (fragmentA == null) {
    fragmentA = FragmentA.newInstance();
}
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container_content, fragmentA, "my-tag");
ft.commit();
```

Since the `FragmentA` was created the first time it ran, it doesn't go into the if block. But what I noticed that the `onCreate()` of `FragmentA` returns a different instance of the ViewModel. I have the following code in `FragmentA`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle sI) {
    super.onCreate(sI);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    Log.i("test", "ViewModel-> " + mViewModel.toString());
}
```

The log prints:

```
ViewModel-> com.myapp.MyViewModel@ed93f63
```

the first time I create `FragmentA` and then

```
ViewModel-> com.myapp.MyViewModel@ff3eee4
```

after I call `ft.replace()`.

So, I'm confused as to why would `ViewModelProviders` return a different instance of the `ViewModel` the second time around even though `FragmentA` is not null (since it doesn't enter the if block, I assume it is not null)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel):

> A ViewModel is always created in association with a scope (an fragment or an activity) and will be **retained as long as the scope is alive**. E.g. if it is an Activity, until it is finished.

The scope of `ViewModel` is bound to the scope of input Fragment / Activity.

- Activity: when it is **destroyed & not caused by configuration change**
- Fragment: when it is **destroyed & not caused by configuration change** (i.e. removed from `FragmentManager`)

In other words, the `FragmentA` is destroyed when you replace it with `FragmentB`, so its associated `ViewModel` instance is removed.

---

When you call `ViewModelProviders.of(fragment)` to get a `ViewModel`, at the end it hands off this task to `ViewModelStore`, which stores our `ViewModel` instances.

And let us deep dive into the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-1.0-dev/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java#1730) of `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment-1.0.0`

```
@CallSuper
public void onDestroy() {
    mCalled = true;
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    boolean isChangingConfigurations = activity != null && activity.isChangingConfigurations();
    if (mViewModelStore != null && !isChangingConfigurations) {
        mViewModelStore.clear();
    }
}
```

Therefore the `ViewModel` instance is removed because of this call `mViewModelStore.clear();`

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thanks for the pointing to the doc as well. `ft.replace()` does work like `remove()` where it actually destroys the fragment. The ViewModel doesn't restore because it wasn't destroyed by a config change. Makes sense now!